# Angular show and hide subitem

Tags: angular

I have the following HTML code (I can't change this HTMl code).
An item list each of these items has a subcategory.
When I click on the button "show subcategory" the subcategory should be shown only from this item. In my example all subcategories are shown.

```
<div class="item">
        <div class="wrapper-main-item">
            <div class="main-item">
                <h2>Description</h2>
                <button (click)="showSubItem()">show subcategory</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
        <textarea name="description"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="wrapper-main-item">
        <div class="main-item">
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <button (click)="showSubItem()">show subcategory</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sub-item" *ngIf="showSubItem">
    <textarea name="description"></textarea>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that only the subcategory is shown where I click and not all subcategories open?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop your items of list using `ngFor`. In here, you need to maintain an extra property like `isShowSubitem` to show and hide relevant sub-item. If you are getting data from the server side, You need to modify that array including this property before looping the items.

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9grcm9?file=src/test/test/test.component.ts)

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list" class="item">
  <div class="wrapper-main-item">
    <div class="main-item">
      <h2>Description</h2>
      <button (click)="showSubItem(item.id)">show subcategory</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="item.isShowSubitem" class="sub-item">
    <textarea name="description"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
  list = [
    {
      id: 1,
      item: {
        name: 'test',
      },
      subItem: {
        name: 'sub-test',
      },
      isShowSubitem: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      item: {
        name: 'test',
      },
      subItem: {
        name: 'sub-test',
      },
      isShowSubitem: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      item: {
        name: 'test',
      },
      subItem: {
        name: 'sub-test',
      },
      isShowSubitem: false,
    },
  ];


  showSubItem(id: number) {
    this.list = this.list.map((item: any) => {
      return item.id === id
        ? { ...item, ...{ isShowSubitem: !item.isShowSubitem } }
        : item;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> (I can't change this HTMl code).

Then you have a big problem (but have solution)

You can create a directive with selector `.item`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.item',
  standalone:true
})
export class ItemDirective {
  time:number=0;
  @HostListener('click',['$event.target']) click(){
    this.time=new Date().getTime();
  }
}
```

In your .ts you use ViewChildren to get all the "ItemsDirective". So in submit -enclosed by a setTimeout- you can know the "index" of the element selected

```
  @ViewChildren(ItemDirective) itemsDirective:QueryList<ItemDirective>
  showSubItem(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      const itemsToArray=this.itemsDirective.toArray()
      const itemSelected=itemsToArray.reduce((a:any,b:any)=>a.time>b.time?a:b)
      const index=itemsToArray.findIndex(x=>x==itemSelected)
      this.result="You click on the "+index+" element"
  
    })
  }
```

See [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsnuri?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fitem.directive.ts,src%2Findex.html)

NOTE: Really I can not understand the "*ngIf=showSubItem" (as is a function always is true), Idem about the two text-areas, idem not use a *ngFor, idem about...